# Executing Report with No Parameters Displays SSRS UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am migrating a working C# ASP.Net web application from Visual Studio 2008/SQL Server 2005 into Visual Studio 2010/SQL Server 2008 R2.
After the migration, the behavior of one of the reports has changed.

Whenever this report is executed with parameters, it behaves as it did in the old version.  Whenever this report is executed with 
NULL parameters, the SSRS UI is displayed instead of the report page created for null parameter input.

I am using a ReportViewer object to render the reports to the web application.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Here is the HTML markup

```
<div>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:58px; border:solid 1px #919b9c">
                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
                     ZoomMode="Percent" ZoomPercent="100">
                    <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://qrmdata3.chs.net/ReportServer"/>
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is the C# code page call to the reportviewer instance.

```
//// Set report properties and render the report
rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/PCA/Production/PCAFollowUps";
rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: I think the fact you did a migration is less important than the fact that you're running a report with no parameters. I changed your title accordingly.